# Doxygen and external dot file.

Tags: doxygen, dot

I want to include an external dot diagram to my doxygen documentation -- in `\mainpage My Personal Index Page`.  How would I go about it?

Would I include it as an attached png or can I have doxygen generate the diagram itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\dotfile` command to reference a dot file from inside a doxygen comment block.

Doxygen will run `dot` and include the resulting image in the generated documentation.

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddotfile for more info.